# PL SQL Triggers multiples conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

This is for a school projet.

I got a table Surgeon with the following data : idSurgeon, idType, idRoom, surgeryDate, BeginTime, EndTime. (BeginTime and EndTime are integer for the hour of the surgery). I try creating a trigger that can prevent 2 surgeries at the same time in the same room.

```
CREATE TRIGGER I_PreventSurgery
BEFORE INSERT ON SURGEON
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ( (old.surgeryDate = new.surgeryDate) and (old.idRoom = 
new.idRoom) );
BEGIN
IF ( ((:new.BeginTime >= old.BeginTime) and (:new.BeginTime >= 
:old.EndTime)) and ((:new.EndTime <= old.EndTime) and (:EndTime >= 
:old.BeginTime)) );
THEN
raise_application_error(-20100, '2 surgeries at the same times'); 
END;
/
```

This trigger doesn't work : I got a compilation error. Even if I try to type show errors and I dont get it.

What's my error ? how to correct the conditions ?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: You have an extraneous semicolon at the end of your WHEN clause. Also, I don't think that clause is necessary for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to check that theres no surgeries at the same date, same room and same time. I remove the semicolon at the end of the when clause and I still have a compilation error.

Comment: Precisions : same time = (BeginTime and EndTime --> 2 integers values).

Comment: @Seyran can you show me how you do it ?

Comment: Will your trigger work? It fires only on insert,so what is the old for it, am I right?

Comment: old = value already in the table surgeon.

Comment: Here's the error message :LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/125  PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'ENDTIME'
2/157  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
  following:
  * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem then
  <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
  like4 likec between overlaps || multiset year day member
  submultiset
  The symbol ";" was ignored.

5/4  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
  following:
  if

Answer (score 2):

Within your trigger, you have to do a `select` that looks for other rows in `SURGEON` that overlap with the new row. Comparing `:old` with `:new` only works when `updating`, and probably the only reason to do so is to determine if any key field (room, date, time) has changed; if not, you might want to skip the collision check.

Comment: Can you show me how to make my trigger work to prevent an insert ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGirard look at Seyran's answer

Answer (score 1):

(sorry for not well English)
If it's for school project easiest way is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER I_PreventSurgery
BEFORE INSERT ON SURGEON
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   for R in (select *
               from SURGEON T
              where T.IDROOM = :new.idroom
                and T.SURGERYDATE = :new.surgerydate
                 and :new.begintime <= T.endtime and :new.endtime >= T.begintime)
   loop
      raise_application_error(-20100, '2 surgeries at the same times');
   end loop;

end;
```

This one sample shows how to solve this problem with unique index check.
It doesn't include update case for old records, covers only adding new records to table.

If it will be working application (which is unlikely, 
but nonetheless) I'll do the following, first of all create a table

```
-- Create table
create table SURGEONBYHOUR
(
  uniqid VARCHAR2(19) not null
);
```

then the unique index

```
-- Create/Recreate indexes 
create unique index I_SURGEONBYHOUR_UNIQID on SURGEONBYHOUR (UNIQID);
```

the trigger will be this one

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER I_PreventSurgery
BEFORE INSERT ON SURGEON
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   for li in :new.begintime .. :new.endtime
   loop
      insert into SURGEONBYHOUR
         (UNIQID)
      values
         (to_char(:new.surgerydate, 'yyyymmdd') ||
          lpad(:new.idroom, 4, '0') || lpad(li, 2, '0'));
   end loop;
end;
```

For test: `SURGEON` table is
-- Create table

```
CREATE TABLE SURGEON
(
  IDSURGEON   NUMBER,
  IDTYPE      NUMBER,
  IDROOM      VARCHAR2(4),
  SURGERYDATE DATE,
  BEGINTIME   NUMBER,
  ENDTIME     NUMBER
);
```

values for test

```
insert into surgeon
   (idsurgeon, idtype, idroom, surgerydate, begintime, endtime)
values
   (1, 1, 52, '01/01/17', 11, 13);

insert into surgeon
   (idsurgeon, idtype, idroom, surgerydate, begintime, endtime)
values
   (2, 1, 53, '01/01/17', 12, 15);
insert into surgeon
   (idsurgeon, idtype, idroom, surgerydate, begintime, endtime)
values
   (3, 2, 52, '01/01/17', 12, 14);
```

Comment: you can shorten you check and make it work correctly: instead of `(:new.begintime <= T.endtime and :new.begintime >= t.begintime  or :new.endtime >= T.begintime and :new.endtime <= T.endtime ))`, just write `:new.begintime < T.endtime and :new.endtime > T.begintime`. You check fails to detect the collision between  e.g. :new=01:00-05:00 and T=02:00-04:00

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `;` which is at end of `when` and also from `if` condition and check.